# Jquery mobile select menu duplicating on document load

Tags: jquery, html, select, jquery-mobile

I have this simple select menu, im trying in project

```
<select data-mini="true">
  <option value="small">One</option>
  <option value="medium">Two</option>
  <option value="large">Three</option>
</select>
```

This works fine. But I am loading my header and footer on document load (as shown below). This seems to be creating two nested select menus, sometimes this nested menu tends to go upto 3 or 4 levels.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#header').load("iphoneHeader.html");
            $('#footer').load("iPadFooter.html");
        });
```

[image]

Why is this error popping? Are there any workaround for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post your HTML and the contents of ```iphoneHeader.html``` and ```iPadFooter.html``` files.

Answer (score 1):

Never use document ready with jQuery Mobile.

You should also use predefined jQuery Mobile page events.

First of all, jQuery Mobile uses Ajax to load content. Because of this, document ready will usually load before jQuery has actually loaded predefined page content. Even worse, document ready can trigger several times (more than two). This is also the case with unproperly attached click/tap events.

That's why it is important to use jQuery Mobile events.

If you want to trigger something on app start you would use [mobileinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/mobileinit/) event.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
  //apply overrides here
});
```

On the other hand, if you want to trigger something on certain page init you would use [pagecreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/) event.

```
$(somePageID).on("pagecreate", function(){
  //apply overrides here
});
```

Find more about jQuery Mobile events [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/).